# How to automatically kill a Kubernetes pod that uses too much CPU?

Tags: performance, kubernetes, automation

I administrate kubernetes clusters running software that is not always perfect. Some have memory leaks, some have cpu leaks, some have both.

I would like to automatically kill the leaking pods. The ones who leak memory are easy, I just put a memory limit and they die eventually when they reach the limit. However CPU seems more tricky. I do not want to put a CPU limit, that will just make them slower and not kill them.

These days I visit regularly the grafana showing the prometheus cpu charts, and once in a while I can spot a pod stuck in an infinite loop, or a pod increasing its CPU usage steadily. I then kill them manually.

I believe no such feature is standard in kubernetes, but I wonder if a plugin exists, or a simple hack.

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66996065/kubernetes-how-to-restart-pod-on-memory-limit-threshold#:~:text=If%20a%20Container%20allocates%20more,other%20type%20of%20runtime%20failure.)

Comment: @asktyagi the link is about memory limits.

Comment: I believe answer is in discussion itself, you can use probes to find container or application health and kubelet will kill it for you based on your policies.

Comment: Do you have any say as to what resides in the pod images either during the build or with a base image? My guess is you're going to need to implement a liveness probe via a command to check CPU usage and let it die if it goes above a threshold.

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669380/can-you-auto-destroy-a-kubernetes-pod-deployment).

Comment: @asktyagi Oh I see. My issue is that the applications claim they are healthy. They just use a lot of CPU.

Comment: @MattW I could always edit the images to change the probes, but I would rather implement a Kubernetes plugin than doing that instead. If it doesn't exist already.

Comment: @AbhijithChitrapu I'm not sure it's related to my question.

Comment: As per my knowledge we cannot kill a Pod automatically apart from resource management.